# I can ping google.com but nothing else?

Tags: networking, server, dns, ethernet

Something got messed up with my network setting after I defined a static IP. it took me a while to make it working again but now there some weird symptoms.
One of those is that can't resolve dns anymore.
I can `ping google.com` with no problem but pinging microsoft.com, godaddy.com or even 8.8.8.8 gets me `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

The machine is an I7, 32Gb ram, running Ubuntu server 20.04, mostly headless. using ssh.

Other devices on my network doesn't have the problem.

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:22:f6:ee:c8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a02:14c:805f:ffc5:1ac0:4dff:fe41:3e93  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::1ac0:4dff:fe41:3e93  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:c0:4d:41:3e:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 331527  bytes 83760648 (83.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 182973  bytes 52213897 (52.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0x53200000-53220000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 209338  bytes 12397801 (12.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 209338  bytes 12397801 (12.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

my /etc/resolv.conf keeps getting cleaned up every reboot to this state:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
```

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: ['192.168.1.101/24']
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 192.168.1.1, 212.143.0.1, 194.90.0.1, '2a02:148::1', '2a02:149::>
```

Any ideas what went wrong and how to fix it?

Btw, pinging IP6 addresses does work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an entry smt like this in your routing table.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0      [your gateway]    255.255.255.0     U       0    0       0 iface
```

this is a sample netplan conf

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp3s0:
        addresses:
            - 10.10.10.2/24
        gateway4: 10.10.10.1
        nameservers:
            search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
            addresses: [10.10.10.1, 1.1.1.1]
```

try adding gateway to your netplan conf and netplan apply.

Comment: It worked! Thank You!